# Posting very complex data structures through ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, web, model-view-controller

The file fmOrderIn.cshtml is a view that contains a complex form:

```
@model MVF2.Models.FarmOrderModel
… 
<form method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><label>Nº Encomenda</label></td>
            <td><input asp-for="encID" readonly="readonly" style="background-color:lightgray;" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label>Farmácia</label></td>
            <td><input asp-for="farmDetails.cliNome" readonly="readonly" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label>Contactos</label></td>
            <td><input asp-for="farmDetails.cliTelefone[0]" readonly="readonly" /><input asp-for="farmDetails.cliTelefone[1]" readonly="readonly" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label>Rua</label></td>
            <td><input asp-for="farmDetails.locRua" readonly="readonly" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label>Localidade</label></td>
            <td><input asp-for="farmDetails.locLocalidade" readonly="readonly" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label>Código Postal</label></td>
            <td><input asp-for="farmDetails.locCodPostal" readonly="readonly" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.aSelVM.SelectedArm)</td>
            <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.aSelVM.SelectedArm, Model.aSelVM.ArmList, "Seleccionar...")</td>
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.aSelVM.SelectedArm)
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.aSelVM.SelectedArmLoc)</td>
            <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.aSelVM.SelectedArmLoc, Model.aSelVM.ArmLocList)</td>
        </tr>

        @Html.Partial("_ProdPartialView", Model.pVM)
```

The file _ProdPartialView.cshtml is that partial view that contains:

```
    @model MVF2.Models.ViewModels.prodTableViewModel

    @foreach (var p in Model.pTable.AsEnumerable())
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@p.Codigo</td>
            <td>@p.ProdNome</td>
            <td><input asp-for="@p.Data.Date" type="date" /></td>
            <td><input asp-for="@p.QtdVendida" /></td>
            <td><input asp-for="@p.QtdBonus" /></td>
            <td>@p.QtdTotal</td>
            <td><input asp-for="@p.PercDesconto" /></td>
            <td><select asp-for="@p.TipoDesconto" asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<DiscountEnumType>()">
                </select></td>
        </tr>
    }
```

Now, I want to post all this information to the controller through a button.

I tried some `<input type="submit" … />` and also a `@Html.ActionLink` helpers, but I didn't manage to transfer all this information.

Could you help me?

Thank you very much.

Comment: "but I didn't manage to transfer all this information." is quite vague.

Comment: You can't transfer anything because there is no way for your form to communicate with the controller. You are looking for `asp-action ` and `asp-controller` tag helpers.

Comment: Even with asp-action and asp-controller in the ```<button>``` or in the ```<form>```, this doesn't work. The structure that I am trying to pass is very complex. Here goes:

```
    public class FarmOrderModel
    {
...
        public bool isPrioritario { get; set; }
        public FarmDetailsModel farmDetails { get; set; }
        public armSelViewModel aSelVM { get; set; }
        public prodTableViewModel pVM { get; set; }
        public string observs { get; set; }
    }
```
It has subclasses has you can see….

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simplified your model but you can use the same format for the rest of the properties

fmOrderIn.cshtml:

```
@model FarmOrderModel

<form method="post" action="@Url.Action("Method", "Home")">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><label>Nº Encomenda</label></td>
            <td><input asp-for="encID" readonly="readonly" style="background-color:lightgray;" /></td>
        </tr>

        @Html.Partial("_ProdPartialView", Model)
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Click Me" />
</form>
```

And the Url.Action("Method", "Home") will go to the url /Home/Method so you will need to change that to the correct action method you want to hit

_ProdPartialView.cshtml:

```
@model FarmOrderModel

@for (int i = 0; i < Model.pTable.Count; i++)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input asp-for="@Model.pTable[i].Codigo" />
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```